# How to remove object constraint from parent bone?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I am trying to use an object constraint to make a bone tip follow a path. However, when I try to assign the constraint in pose mode the parent bones also get the constraint. Is there a way to remove a constraint from a parent bone but not the child?

Comment: maybe you've confused object constraint with bone contraint, make sure that you have selected a bone in Pose mode and opened the good panel (Bone Constraints, not Object Constraints)